# How dispatch.yaml works in practice

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, microservices

I understand that the role of `dispatch.yaml` is to redirect requests to the suitable microservice.

Below is my dispatch.yaml:

```
dispatch:
  - url: "*/favicon.ico"
    service: default

  - url: "*/tweet/*"
    service: tweet
```

The project has two services: `default` and `tweet`. Using `Flask`, the handlers are configured like this:

## Default Service

**my-project/default_service/default.yaml**

```
service: default
runtime: python37

handlers:

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

**my-project/default_service/main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def root():
    response = { 'message': "Hello from the Default service" }
    return jsonify(response)
```

## Tweet Service

**my-project/tweet_service/tweet.yaml**

```
service: service-job
runtime: python37

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

**my-project/tweet_service/main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/tweet')  # handles /tweet route
def root():
    response = { 'message': "Hello from the Tweet service" }
    return jsonify(response)
```

## Question:

When the request `https://tweet-dot-my-project.appspot.com/tweet` is made, the responses is a `502 Bad Gateway` error. Why is this? The `dispatch.yaml` should have taken the following steps:

1. Noticed the `/tweet` path and calls upon the `tweet` microservice to handle it.
2. Inside `tweet.py`, `the @app.route('/tweet')` handle should have been called and return the response.

Please let me know where I have misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have some issues in your examples.

In your `my-project/tweet_service/tweet.yaml` the service isn't `tweet`. The problem maybe comme to here.

Then, the dispatch allow to not directly query the sub-service `tweet-dot-my-project.appspot.com/tweet` but directly the base service`my-project.appspot.com/tweet` and the query is redirected to the right `tweet` service

Finally, there is an abnormal behavior on AppEngine.

**If you have only 1 endpoint, like /tweet**

Here, in your `dispatch.yaml`, you redirect all the url under `*/tweet/` to be handle by the `tweet` service. But the `/tweet` endpoint isn't redirected. Update your dispatch without the last `/` on tweet

```
  - url: "*/tweet*"
    service: tweet
```

**If you have other sub-endpoints, like /tweet/other**
This time, your `dispatch.yaml` is valid, with and without the last `/`

This doesn't explain the `502 Bad Gateway` error. So, I got it in my tests. Look at my code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/tweet')  # handles /tweet route
def root():
    response = { 'message': "Hello from the Tweet service" }
    return jsonify(response)

@app.route('/tweet/other')  # handles /tweet route
def root():
    response = { 'message': "Hello from the Tweet/other service" }
    return jsonify(response)
```

I copy paste too quickly your code, and I have 2 `root()` functions. That causes service crash and thus a 502 errors.

Check your REAL code (*the provided code isn't fully correct, I imagine there is more than this 2 endpoints*) and the logs, find your crash cause, and fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and further clarification, but I still get the same error. I corrected the two `root()` and also removed `/` in `url: "*/tweet*"`. When I visit `my-project.appspot.com/tweet`, I get same error. If you would be so kind, please look at my code here: https://github.com/puoygae/deploy-microservices

Comment: I would speak about error in the file. For me I was 2 root() in the same python file and the script failed because of this error. Error 502 is an internal problem, your app crash while the processing. Check your indent, space and tab indent consistency,... something wrong happens